# tips to remove camera lens reflection from object

Tags: lens, reflection

I have several highly polished metallic gemstones of this variety that are domed and the lens reflection covers the metallic pale colored veining that NEEDS to be seen. I tried coating the gemstone with vaseline, the image result was unacceptable.
I've used an all white tent totally enclosed with LED lighting at all angles. Anyone have suggestions how to eliminate the lens reflection off the surface. I do not have 3rd party photo editing software, such as Photoshop. I wouldn't even know what tools to use if I did have access to Photoshop.  Thanks for any help!
[gemstone http://bulksell.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SingleList&sellingMode=RelistItem&draftId=665549166003](http://bulksell.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SingleList&sellingMode=RelistItem&draftId=665549166003)

Comment: Can you post an example photo?

Comment: Your link just leads to an eBay login page.

Comment: I'm tardy with my reply!  Sorry bout that photo attempt that obviously didn't work, and Thanks for letting me know. I didn't know how to HTML a photo from my personal computer folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is not to create them. The aswer from Caleb is very good one.

I would add only that, some reflections comes from surfaces like water or glass (polished stones as well).
Those can be elimitated by using **Polarizing Filter**.

But once flares/light refletions are there one may use some post processing techniques. There are some pragrams to help to reach quite good result:

1. Photoshop - [How to Remove Glare from Glasses in Photoshop](https://phlearn.com/remove-glare-glasses-photoshop)
2. GIMP - [GIMP Tutorial- Remove Glare on Glasses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nt67pIsHE8E)
3. Aperture - [How to remove lens flare from iPhone photos in Aperture](https://www.gadgetdaily.xyz/how-to-remove-lens-flare-from-iphone-photos-in-aperture/)

In other programs, it will looks similar.

Comment: SBW, Thanks so much for offering your recommendations, just the best too! I haven't tried the Polarizing Filter! I will give that suggestion a go too! I'm so excited to have some possible solutions and the website links!  So great both answers I received!

Answer (score 3):

> Anyone have suggestions how to eliminate the lens reflection off the surface.

There are a few things you can do:

1. **Block the light.** The only way you could see a reflection of the camera is if there's light bouncing off the camera. Prevent stray light from hitting the camera in the first place, and that light can't bounce onto the subject and then back to the sensor. For example, you could shoot through a hole in a piece of black velvet, with the camera far enough behind the velvet that stray light won't hit it. You can also position barriers around the light box so that light isn't bouncing all around the room and eventually lighting the camera.
2. **Move the lights.** If the lights or well-lit surfaces are very close to the subject, they may be directly lighting the camera as well. Moving them away from the subject a bit might change the angle so that the camera isn't lit so strongly.
3. **Adjust the subject or camera.** If you've got some broad, flat surfaces, they may be acting like a mirror. Rotating the subject slightly, or moving the camera a bit, might change the angle so that the camera isn't in the area that the gem reflects.
4. **Use a longer lens.** A lens with longer focal length will let you move the camera farther from the subject, which will reduce the size of any reflection. Moving the camera farther away will also reduce the amount of light hitting the camera, and therefore it will reduce the reflected image of the camera.

Comment: Caleb Thanks so much for reaching out and giving recommendations, some of which I've previously attempted. I'll give it another go with the suggestions I haven't tried! Again Thanks!